# How to keep alive instances of classes Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have created information system with 3 layers(Client, Server, Database) in `Java`. I am using for communications between Client and Server `Tomcat 7 server`, `Servlet`, `HTTP restfull API`. Class `Obchod` in server creating new instances of data classes which communicate with database.

Topically when i start server no instances of data classes are created and when client send request for data, server create instance of data classes and loads all data from database to local arrays and then send requested data to client, after this request are all data lost and server waiting for requests...

So i need this instances which stores data in arrays keep alive for next requests.

Class `Obchod`

```
@Path("/obchod")
public class Obchod
{
    int size = 20;

    // Data classes
    Uzivatel     u = new Uzivatel(size);
    Zbozi        z = new Zbozi(size);
    Skladem      s = new Skladem(size);
    ProdaneZbozi p = new ProdaneZbozi(size);
    KoupeneZbozi k = new KoupeneZbozi(size);


    @POST
    @Path("/addUser")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void addUser(String str)
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);   
        u.pridej(Integer.toString(u.maxID() + 1), obj.getString("Jmeno"), obj.getString("Prijmeni"), obj.getString("Datum_Narozeni"), obj.getString("Pozice"));
    }
    ...
    //next methods
    ...
}
```

`Web.xml` in dynamic web project(Eclipse)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WSdemo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>obchod</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web.xml i just add `listener`:

```
  <listener>
        <listener-class>obchod.Obchod</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

And in Obchod.java:

```
@Path("/obchod")
public class Obchod  implements ServletContextListener
{
    int size = 20;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext();
        sc.setAttribute("Uzivatel", new Uzivatel(size));
        sc.setAttribute("Zbozi", new Zbozi(size));
        sc.setAttribute("Skladem", new Skladem(size));
        sc.setAttribute("ProdaneZbozi", new ProdaneZbozi(size));
        sc.setAttribute("KoupeneZbozi", new KoupeneZbozi(size));   
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/addUser")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void addUser(@Context ServletContext context, String str)
    {
        Uzivatel u = (Uzivatel) context.getAttribute("Uzivatel");

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);   
        u.pridej(Integer.toString(u.maxID() + 1), obj.getString("Jmeno"), obj.getString("Prijmeni"), obj.getString("Datum_Narozeni"), obj.getString("Pozice"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the way how Java Servlet works. Look at this image: [image]

In overall:

- The `ServletContext` lives as long as the webapp lives. It's been
  shared among all requests in all sessions.
- The `HttpSession` lives as long as the client is interacting with the webapp with the same
  browser instance and the session hasn't timed out at the server side
  yet. It's been shared among all requests in the same session.
- The
  `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` lives as long as the
  client has sent it until the complete response (the webpage) is
  arrived. It is not being shared elsewhere.
- Any `Servlet, Filter and
  Listener` lives as long as the webapp lives. They are being shared
  among all requests in all sessions.
- Any `attribute` which you set in
  `ServletContext, HttpServletRequest and HttpSession` will live as
  long as the object in question lives.

Why you want to store data in arrays in your application?

**To improve performance??** Use `caching`, so the values will be stored in cache, and the methods will not query the DB with specified time range.

**If you want to have updated information**, change values in DB, using `Transactions`. When `user A` will update the value, next user will fetch new value directly from DB.

Comment: I want use arrays, because its simple for me and i know how to work with them. I guess when i will load data from DB to arrays and client will want read data, its will be fast enough for me. I can't read data directly from DB because its school project and i have terms for this project. It is possible stote all my data in ServletContext instead of arrays? Is here any solution how to use arrays and keep them alive when client is not connected?